# Magento 2: Not loading CSS and JS after successful installation in windows

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

CSS and JS not loading after installation of Magento 2 default template

```
OS: Windows 10
Xampp Control panel V3.2.2
PHP version: 5.6.28
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32)
phpmyadmin Version information: 4.5.1
```

[image][image]

Comment: Did you run the static content deploy command?

Comment: Yes. Run this command: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [locales]`

Answer (score 15):

Its working when i did the following changes:

Remove all files from `pub/static` folder but not **.htaccess**

Go to **app/etc/di.xml**

Replace ('Symlink' --> 'Copy')

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink
```

by

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

Answer (score 7):

Step1 :- Go to var folder and check .htaccess file is available or not. If it is not available then copy .htaccess file in default magento2 and paste.

Step2 :- Go to pub\static folder and check .htaccess file is available or not. If it is not available then copy .htaccess file in default magento2 and paste.

Step3 :- Login your ssh/putty and go to root directory and run below command

a). rm -rf var/*

b). rm -rf pub/static/*

c). php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

d). chmod -R 777 var pub/static

Step4 :- Refresh your link.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the simplest solution if showing version name in css path**

like : pub/static/version323334/

then run this query in my sql

```
 INSERT INTO 'core_config_data' ('path', 'value') 
VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
```

after that clear the config cache

```
 bin/magento cache:clean config
```

you can also disable static file version form admin

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Changing the

> Options +FollowSymLinks

to

> Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

in the .htaccess file inside the **pub** folder in your Magento root directory fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are facing theming issue after Installation in magento 2. You can follow these steps :**

1. **Run mysql this query :**

> INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign',
>   0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;

2. **For local machine run this mysql query:**  If dbname us you

> UPDATE  `dbname`.`core_config_data` SET  `value` =  '0' WHERE 
>   `core_config_data`.`path` LIKE  '%web/seo/use_rewrites%';

3. **Remove all the files from pub and var directory :**

> sudo rm -rf var/di var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/cache/
>   pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs/ 
>   pub/static/deployed_version.txt

4. **Give Permission to var and pub directories of your project :**

> sudo chmod -R 777 var/* pub/*

5. ** Command for Upgrade Setup :**

> sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

6. **Command for Deploy content :**

> sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

After these steps, you will be able to see proper theme.

Comment: Life saver +1..

Answer (score 2):

Might be the issue at mod rewrite. Please check the mod rewrite setting at the server. If you have using apache then use below steps for enabling mod rewrite

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete everything except .htaccess in pub\static and refresh the page will resolve the issue .

Answer (score 0):

1.Just delete var/view-processed/pub folder.Also delete pub/static/frontend/ all folders.

2.In mysql core_config_data,check whether dev/static/sign has scope-default ,scope id- 0 and value 0.If field not present, create it.

3.Then run 
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
 php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

In command line Magento root directory use the following commands.

1. **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**
2. **php bin/magento cache:clean**
3. **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

   ```
              or
   ```

   **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**