# Magento 2 css and js not working after install

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

I had a problem with magento 2, where in localhost I created the website and everything was fine, after importing to my server the CSS and JS was not working.

I search for so many answers and still no luck, after awhile I decided to simply start again, so I imported magento to my server, installed it with no errors, but when I entered the home page the CSS and JS does not work.

Here's a couple of things I already tried:

```
php bin/magento setup:content-static:deploy
```

deleting the static folder and keep the .htacess and run

```
 php bin/magento setup:content-static:deploy
```

Replacing `Symlink` with `Copy`

```
Checking the folders permissions
```

Here is the link of my website: http://maquinasdeoutrostempos.pt/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check this link which could help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154728/magento-2-not-loading-css-and-js-after-successful-installation-in-windows?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Venkatesh i tried it but still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried this "INSERT INTO 'core_config_data' ('path', 'value') 
VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;" in Database.

Comment: @Venkatesh it says that i have a syntax error in : ('path', 'value') VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0

Comment: Please try this "INSERT INTO `core_config_data`(`path`, `value`) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`=0;"

Comment: @Venkatesh i did it, and i clear the config cache, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Could you check .htaccess file is present in pub/static

Comment: @Venkatesh it is there

Comment: Could you follow the steps given in this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212514/refused-to-apply-style-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supported-s?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Venkatesh copied the .htacess from here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/pub/static/.htaccess, but still no luck

Comment: Are the files in the correct `pub` folder? you are looking to the `pt_PT` inside `pub`, but sometime during deploys Magento will only populate the `en_US` folder. Check that dir and if it's empty run `php bin/magento setup:content-static:deploy pt_PT`

Comment: @circlesix i always deploy to pt_PT  with : php bin/magento setup:content-static:deploy pt_PT, but still doesn't work.

Comment: @ruben, inside the `pub` dir, when you navigate all the way down to the files that are kicking the 404 error on the site, what do you see? and what are the file permission and ownership?

Comment: @circlesix the permissions are 644

Comment: Ok, that might be the problem. I would try getting the path to just one file in the pub folder, a css or js file. Try to hit that file with the full path in the browser. It's going to fail (we already know that from the console errors) but then changing just that file to 755. if you still can't hit it, change it to 775. and finally 777. That might be the reason these files can't be hit.

Answer (score 5):

1] Check whether file permissions are given properly to all the Magento files

2] In your database run below query into "`core_config_data`" table and check you get any result or not

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%static/sign%'
```

3] If no then run below query

```
insert into core_config_data (config_id, scope, scope_id, path, value) values (null, 'default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
```

or

4] if "`dev/static/sign`" value is already exist into table set that **1** to **0**

run php bin/magento c:f , php bin/magento s:s:d -f

I hope this solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case - I missed to add the **AllowOverride** to apache config during install.

Add the following to the end of Apache 000-default.conf (or whatever your apache config file is):

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

After adding - restart apache, solved the static content not loading issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have well your `.htaccess`in the root project location
2. Check if you have well the css files in your current theme.
3. Check if you have well the right permissions `755` in `app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/web`, `app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/web/css/*.css`
4. remove the content folders of `pub/static`, `var/cache`, `var/page_cache`, `var/view_preprocessed`
5. Launch this commands:

   - `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/luma pt_PT -f`
   - `php bin/magento cache:clean`
   - `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: When i go in app/design/frontend/Magento that folder is empty, don't know why

Comment: Are you using a default `Magento/luma` ? you did not create a new theme ?

Comment: I did not, i was going to edit the css just

Comment: ok, so it's normal that you have `app/design/frontend/Magento` empty

Comment: still the css and js won't work

Answer (score 0):

For me it was simply because mod_rewrite wasn't enabled.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and

```
service apache2 restart
```

Happy Coding!