# after installing magento 2.2.2 theme my front-end and admin panel is not loading properly! how can i solve this?

Tags: frontend, backend, magento2.2.2, js-css, not-found

after installing magento 2.2.2  theme my front-end and admin panel is not loading properly! how can i solve this[image]?
enter image description here

[image]

Comment: because your css is not properly loaded, to verify you can check the css paths in source code

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154728/magento-2-not-loading-css-and-js-after-successful-installation-in-windows?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: have you installed magento on your local system or on some server ? could you also mention what OS are you using ?

Comment: its installed in my server. am using windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Please run below commands from Magento 2 root directory.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static/
```

If it is still not running then...

Run following query in database

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');
```

or if you have already value for that path, then change it from **1** to **0**.

Then flush cache and deploy static content as follows.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static/
```

Comment: sir isn`t it a duplicate question and needs to mark it as a duplicate ?

Comment: It is not duplicate. I also mentioned another case in my answer.