# CSS is not loading?

Tags: magento-2.1, css

My web server initially pointed to magento root directory, then the site is working properly. Actually it is recommended to point to the pub folder. When i pointed my webserver to pub folder the css is not loading .

Can anyone give a me a solution???Thanks.

Comment: nginx or apache ?

Comment: apache2 webserver

Comment: Try this link. It might help you
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/154734/70848

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `.htaccess` file in your pub directory

download below `.htaccess` file and  put it to pub directory

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1-develop/pub/.htaccess

Comment: Tq for your Concern.

Comment: @BhaskarCPothineni is this solution solve your problem ? if yes then feel free to mark as accepted