# CSS / JS Not Loading on FrontEnd after flushing Cache with Custom Theme

Tags: magento2, css

I'm having issues with getting my custom **Magento 2 theme** to compile correctly.

I installed it on a remote server and configured it. All is working on that end. I can flush the cache and deploy the static - it seems fine.

However when I **download** the **files** for local **development** the **CSS and JS** is not compiling correctly. The only thing I have changed is the url in the **core_config_data** table to `http://localhost` - When I switch the database to a fresh install of Magento and do a static deploy and remove all `var/cache` etc files it loads back fine.

However, when I change the `env.php` file back to the downloaded DB with the edited URL and I **flush the cache** it goes back to not loading any **CSS files**.

Have followed the guides here.

> [Magento 2 CSS and JavaScript not loading from correct folder](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder)
>
> [Magento 2: Not loading CSS and JS after successful installation in windows](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154728/magento-2-not-loading-css-and-js-after-successful-installation-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pulling the project in your localhost, the first thing you have to do is switch to developer mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

While developing, in order to view the changes of the static files, you should run this command to symlink them with the pub/static folder:

```
php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy
```

After any change, clear the cache and refresh the browser.

If you get it to work with the given commands, read more on how to automate the process with tools like grunt or gulp:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Comment: No, still not working. There's no JS and still no CSS being loaded. I have removed the symlinks in the di.xml file to just copy. It works fine on a fresh install of DB. I'm thinking there's an issue in the DB somewhere. Any ideas?

Comment: @saulable please provide me all the steps that you're following after pulling the installation in your localhost.

Comment: I'm re-pulling now with the working remote copy. Going to double check for you. Something may have corrupted whilst trying all these commands.

Comment: So I pulled down the site again and it seems to be fine. Something must have got corrupted. Have put it in to developer mode, which is great. Also, thanks for the other command. Now need to go set up some gulp and start working. Much appreciated :)